# How to wait for JavaFx MediaPlayer to finish

Tags: javafx

I have a `MediaPlayer` object which plays a video. When the video is finished playing, I want the program to hide the `MediaView` and display different JavaFx entities. However, when I call `player.play()` the program immediately interprets the lines of code which follow, resulting in the `MediaView` not being visible at all.

```
public class Level1Controller implements Initializable {

    File file = new File("ngnl.mp4");
    Media media = new Media(file.toURI().toString());
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    @FXML
    MediaView view = new MediaView();


    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        view.setMediaPlayer(player);
        player.play();

        view.setVisible(false); 
    }
}
```

More buttons and such would be "under" the `MediaView` in the JavaFx hierarchy, so when it is hidden, the underlying stuff would be seen.

Comment: One thing you should recognize about methods run on the JavaFX application thread is that in most circumstances they need to return withing a few ms to not freeze the ui. There are only a handful of methods in the JavaFX API that do block for this reason. `play` only schedules the media to be played, but leaves playing sound&rendering the video for later (managed by the toolkit internally).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't find any official documents that mention this but I'm pretty sure the media file is played on a separate thread under the hood by JavaFX so that it doesn't block the UI thread. This is why you need to use [MediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnEndOfMedia(java.lang.Runnable)):

```
view.setMediaPlayer(player);

player.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
    view.setVisible(false); 
});    

player.play();
```

Comment: Even though you point out the correct way of implementing this, a bit of explanation would greatly improve the quality of this answer. (E.g. why does the original approach not work... (Not that I need that explanation myself, but it would proably be beneficial for the OP and anyone with a similar level of experience reading the answer))