# Javafx playing video in stage and then closing it and opening new stage

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am making a game in JavaFX. Now to beautify it , I have initially made a video that I want to play whenever the application is launched. After that I want to close this video and open the menu of Game.
What I have done is made the video and a 1000x1000 stage. Issue now is that after video is over , stage is not closing [wanna do it automatically].And then how do I open next window ?

Also , I am not able to drag the window around.

P.s. : Beginner with Java fx

```
Parent root_window = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        //you can use underdecorated or transparent.
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        //stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDERDECORATED);
        //grab your root here
        root_window.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                xOffset = event.getSceneX();
                yOffset = event.getSceneY();
            }
        });

        //move around here
        root_window.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                stage.setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset);
                stage.setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset);
            }
        });

        File f = new File( "LogoReveal.mp4");
        Media media = new Media(f.toURI().toURL().toString());
        javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer player = new   javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer(media);
        MediaView viewer = new MediaView(player);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,1000,1000);

        stage.setHeight(1000);
        stage.setWidth(1000);

        root.getChildren().add(viewer);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        player.play();
        stage.close();
```

What I thought was that video will be played sequentially and then window closed.

Comment: Just look at this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807676/how-to-wait-for-javafx-mediaplayer-to-finish)

Comment: @fuggerjaki61 Yes. Solved the issue. Will remove it

Comment: Not sure why the stage shows up at all. After all you immediately close it... Also note that your event handlers refer to different coordinate systems: scene and screen

Comment: @fabian What I thought was that media player will play the video and wait for it to close

Comment: In general calls do not block. The behavour for `play` methods for animation classes is the same: It simply **schedules** updates...

Comment: @fabian Thanks ! Solved drag issue